# Fetching a contacts mailing address using the address label swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I pull a contacts mailing address using the mailing address label?

The function buildContactsAddress_Array below builds an array containing the address label(name) and the address ID. The array is used to populate a tableView where the user can select the address by its name. I have included pretty much all of the related code to try and make things as clear as I can. Thanks in advance.

This is the part I want to change or replace to use address label. Right now it just uses the first/home address.

```
if let firstPostalAddress = (theName.postalAddresses.first),
            let labelValuePair = firstPostalAddress.value(forKey: "labelValuePair") as? AnyObject,
            let finalPostalAddress = labelValuePair.value(forKey: "value") as? CNPostalAddress
        {
            mailAddress = CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: finalPostalAddress, style: .mailingAddress)
```

### }

```
struct contactAddresses
{
    var theLabel: String
    var theID: String
}

private var addressesArray = [contactAddresses]()
private var addressID: String = ""
private var theContactID: String = ""
```

This func pulls the contacts info using the contacts ID.

```
func getContactFromID_Ouote(contactID: String)
    {
        let store = CNContactStore()
        var theName = CNContact()

        let theKeys = [CNContactNamePrefixKey,
                       CNContactGivenNameKey,
                       CNContactFamilyNameKey,
                       CNContactOrganizationNameKey,
                       CNContactPostalAddressesKey,
                       CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)] as! [CNKeyDescriptor]

        do {
            theName = try store.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: contactID, keysToFetch: theKeys)

            contactName = CNContactFormatter.string(from: theName, style: .fullName)!

            contactPrefix = theName.namePrefix
            contactFirst = theName.givenName
            contactLast = theName.familyName
            companyName = theName.organizationName == "" ? "" : theName.organizationName

        } catch {
            print("Fetching contact data failed: \(error)")
        }


        if let firstPostalAddress = (theName.postalAddresses.first),
            let labelValuePair = firstPostalAddress.value(forKey: "labelValuePair") as? NSObject,
            let finalPostalAddress = labelValuePair.value(forKey: "value") as? CNPostalAddress
        {
            mailAddress = CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: finalPostalAddress, style: .mailingAddress)
        }
    }
```

This func puts the contacts addresses into an array. The array is then used to populate a tableView.

```
func buildContactsAddress_Array(contactID: String)
{
    let store = CNContactStore()
    var theName = CNContact()

    let theKeys = [CNContactPostalAddressesKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]

    do {
        theName = try store.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: contactID, keysToFetch: theKeys)

        let postalAddress = theName.postalAddresses
        postalAddress.forEach { (mailAddress) in

            // Strip forst 4 and last 4 from _$!<Home>!$_
            let aaa = mailAddress.label
            let bbb = aaa!.dropLast(4)
            let ccc = bbb.dropFirst(4)

            addressesArray.append(contactAddresses(theLabel: String(ccc), theID: mailAddress.identifier))
        }

        addressesArray.sort { $0.theLabel < $1.theLabel }

    } catch {
        print("Fetching contact addresses failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```

This is the tableView extension. When a cell is tapped, addressID is populated with the ID of the appropriate mailing address.

```
extension QuotePreview_VC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return addressesArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let theCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        theCell.textLabel?.text = addressesArray[indexPath.row].theLabel

        return theCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        addressID = addressesArray[indexPath.row].theID
        populateThePrintFld()
        closeThePicker()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing.

```
if addressesArray.count > 1
        {
            // Grab the address picked by the user in the TV
            if let addressID = addressID
            {
                if let finalPostalAddress = theName.postalAddresses.first(where: { labelValuePair in labelValuePair.identifier == addressID })?.value
                {
                    mailAddress = CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: finalPostalAddress, style: .mailingAddress)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Grab the first available address
            if let firstPostalAddress = (theName.postalAddresses.first),
                let labelValuePair = firstPostalAddress.value(forKey: "labelValuePair") as? NSObject,
                let finalPostalAddress = labelValuePair.value(forKey: "value") as? CNPostalAddress
            {
                mailAddress = CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: finalPostalAddress, style: .mailingAddress)
            }
        }
```